# Can Linux Kernel CONFIG_RETPOLINE be dropped on for Enhanced IBRS systems?

Tags: linux-kernel, gcc

I'm working on a deployment of systems that exclusively use Cascade Lake processors, which support Enhanced IBRS for Spectre v2 mitigation.

I see that in kernel source, if I set spectre_v2=auto on this system, I'll get the enhanced IBRS mitigation (great!): https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blame/master/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/bugs.c#L878

However, if I compile the Linux Kernel with CONFIG_RETPOLINE, gcc will still be instructed to still compile the code with -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blame/master/Makefile#L673

This means that even if the hardware itself is offering processor level protection, the code generation will still have retpolines active.

Case in point: When running KVM on such a system, I still see the presence of _*x86_indirect_thunk** functions take place.

Question: If I am ***exclusively*** deploying on systems that have Cascade Lake++ with Enhanced IBRS, is it "safe" to drop CONFIG_RETPOLINE ... and if not, why?